# Is there always a direct connection between the central nodes in an (undirected graph)?

Tags: networking, graph-theory, networkx

[This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCenter.html) link contains an examples about the graph central nodes, I noticed that if there are more than one central node in a graph G, then a they are always adjacent nodes (means there is a direct link between them)

Also, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmgOe.png) is an example that illustrates the `one` and `two` central nodes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely graph theory question and has no programming aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check counterexample:

```
   *
   |
   *
  / \
 /   \
A     B
 \   /
  \ /
   *
   |
   *
```